# How to pull particular data from Encompass360? Does it has any API or?

Tags: api

I have a client who need a solution which is integrated with the Encompass 360 broker edition. But I don't know about the architecture of the Encompass 360 broker edition. I couldn't find any information from there site (http://www.elliemae.com).

So I'm hoping someone can help me who is currently using this software or who has particular knowledge about the Encompass 360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you've already found this information out, but here is a link to the SDK guide:
http://help.elliemae.com/DocumentationLibrary/360/Encompass360SDKProgrammersGuide.pdf

Hope the guide helps!

Comment: Thanks ,this will be helpful

Comment: The broker edition doesn't allow for access via the SDK, your clients would need banker edition.